# angular ui grid verifying sorted data using ruby selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, angular-ui-grid

I have an angular webpage. One of the page sections (an angular ui grid) contains nearly 1000 rows of data. Each row has 7 columns. (There is no table tag available anywhere in the HTML the grid is made using nested divs) 
At a time only 20 rows will be shown in the page section. Now using ruby and selenium I need to verify whether data displayed in 7th column is sorted in ascending order or not. I tried to do this by reading the contents of the 
angular ui grid to an array of arrays. But at any point of time when I fetch the elements data for only 20 rows are getting stored. After loading this page I tried again by doing a horizontal scroll and fetching the data. 
But still I get only 20 rows of data everytime I try. I believe only the data for the visible rows at the point of execution is only getting fetched. And I think the data is loaded dynamically to 20 rows on demand which 
are visible in the section.

Now what is the best logic I could use to verify whether data displayed in 7th column or any other column is sorted in ascending order or not !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description what I understand is all 1000 rows will be stored in page source during page load. And on demand any 20 rows will be loaded from page source as user scrolls down or scrolls up in the page section. In this case, the best option will be to collect data from the source and store all of it to an array as per need. Which can be done as

```
browser.execute_script("return angular.element("your element.functionWhichloadsallRows)").collect{|e| e.values}
```